# Team Sites - Adding user as an admin

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I add a user as an all team sites (they are over 3000) Admin and an Owner list by PowerShell script? Is it also possible to add a user as an admin and an owner list automatically when creating a new team site?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user as site collection administrator in all site collection in a tenant using PowerShell command below:

```
$AdminURL = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$AdminName = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$NewUser = "newuser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"

#User Names Password to connect 
$Password = Read-host -assecurestring "Enter Password for $AdminName"
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $Password

#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminURL -credential $Credential

$Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

Foreach ($Site in $Sites)
{
    Write-host "Adding Site Collection Admin for:"$Site.URL
    Set-SPOUser -site $Site -LoginName $NewUser -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
}
```

For automatically setting the users as admin when creating a new team site, I recommend you using Windows Task Scheduler to run the PowerShell script.

[How To Automatically Run PowerShell Scripts at a Scheduled Time](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/05/13/automatically-run-powershell-scripts-at-a-scheduled-time.aspx)